# System.Data.SQLite parameters not being substituted

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

```
            conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=nk.db");
            var items = from n in internalMap.storage select n.paramName;
            conn.Open();

            cmd = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE @table_name (name TEXT)",conn);

            //create table for the index

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table_name", j);



            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When this line gets executed "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();" I get the following exception

"SQLite error near \"@table_name\": syntax error"

All the searches I have done seem to indicate that is how you do it.

I have no idea what is wrong

Answer (score 5):

In most databases I've worked with, DDL commands can't be parameterized like this, and even DML statements can't be parameterized by table name (or field name, etc). Generally only *expression values* can be parameterized.

In most cases this is okay, as you usually don't have user-provided data for things like table in names, and there aren't formatting considerations as there could be for things like numbers and dates/times... so plain string substitution in the SQL statement is probably the best you can do, ugly though it may be.